# Как сделать вычисление НОК ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТИ ЧИСЕЛ на SWI-prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Надо реализовать на SWI-prolog вычисление НОК ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТИ ЧИСЕЛ. Я понимаю, как это реализовать для ДВУХ чисел. А вот для ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТИ не могу.

Comment: Может так?

    nod(A,A,A).
    nod(A, B, C) :-
        A > B,
        D is A-B,
        nod(D, B, C).
    nod(A, B, C) :-
        B > A,
        nod(B, A, C).
    
    nok(A, B, X) :-
        nod(A, B, C),
        X is A * B / C.
    
    nok(A, X) :-
        nok1(A, 1, X).
    
    nok1([A|S], C, X) :-
        nok(A, C, C1),
        nok1(S, C1, X).
    nok1([], C, C).

Answer (score 1):

Может [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301761/%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9A-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%98-%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-swi-prolog#comment301800_301761)?

```
nod(A, A, A).
nod(A, B, C) :- A > B, D is A-B, nod(D, B, C).
nod(A, B, C) :- B > A, nod(B, A, C).
nok(A, B, X) :- nod(A, B, C), X is A * B / C.
nok(A, X) :- nok1(A, 1, X).
nok1([A|S], C, X) :- nok(A, C, C1), nok1(S, C1, X).
nok1([], C, C).
```